# Custom post not showing

Tags: custom-post-types

I created custom post type in my functions.php with the following code:

```
function awesome_custom_post_type(){    
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Portfolio',
        'singular_name' => 'Portfolio',
        'add_new' => 'Add Item',
        'all_items' => 'All Items',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'seach_item' => 'Search Portfolio',
        'not_found' => 'No items found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item'        
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' =>  $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicity_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'thumbnail',
                'revisions',

        ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'exclude_from_search' => false
    );
    register_post_type('portfolio',$args);
}
add_action('init','awesome_custom_post_type');
```

The Portfolio is added on my dashboard and I can create a post.
the Problem I see is that,when am in post and click on the permalink it gives    me a 404 error so I can view the post.

How can I view the Post?

I tried adding another file called single-portfolio but still it didn't work:

```
get_header(); ?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
            the_post_navigation();
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks/rewrite rules?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell.I don't think I even know how to  flush a permalink. Beg  your a pardon if I misunderstand something as English sometimes is a barrier for still.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Go to settings, permalinks and save your permalinks once to flush them then see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Noted. It works properly now. Appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your .htaccess file.

Once you will able to update it, your issue will be solved.

Currently your .htaccess file doesnot have "portfolio" slug , so you need to update it.

Hope this helps
Thanks